# What happens when I dismiss a job ad?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

When I dismiss a job ad, what happens?

[image: Dismiss Job Ad]

Does this dismissal impact future recommendations? If so, how? In the example above, if I dismiss that, does it impact recommendations for both Python and Remote jobs?

Does it stop showing this one single job to me without impacting other recommendations?

Comment: An angel loses its wings.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365674/allow-me-to-undismiss-a-company

Answer (score 39, accepted):

<strike>When you dismiss a Job Ad, it *only* affects whether you see that ad or not in the future. It doesn't affect any other system. The job should still show up in job searches and recommendations.</strike>

This is no longer correct. Now our job ad dismissals are synced with the dismiss feature on Stack Overflow Jobs. This means if you dismiss a job ad, it should not show up in any job searches or recommendations.

Currently there's no way to un-dismiss jobs from ads except for the "Undo" button that shows up immediately after dismissal:

[image: Job Dismiss Undo link]

Eventually we want to allow you guys to be able to see which ads you've dismissed and be able to un-dismiss them as you wish, but it's currently low priority. Our reasoning is that most users will dismiss a job ad because it's not relevant to their skills, location, salary range, etc..., and those things don't change very frequently (considering the standard job ad runs for 30 days).

If you accidentally dismiss a job, you can search for it on Stack Overflow Jobs in an Incognito/Private window (or otherwise log out), and then undismiss it from the job detail page (the same goes for Companies).

Comment: I would find more useful to dismiss a company rather them a single job ad.

Comment: @Zanon What if they are only advertising junior roles right now which you are not interested in but next month they advertise "Super Amazing Job" which you are interested in? Additionally some "companies" on the Jobs site are still recruitment agencies so dismissing them might mean dismissing many jobs.

Comment: @AshleyMedway dismissing those recruitment agencies is probably the best reason to allow blocking a company (until the SE team comes in and bans them). There have been a few times where a company signs up and posts a ton of scam "jobs."

Comment: @AshleyMedway, there are some companies that I would never work for. Dismissing every post that they offer is tedious. Banning them would be the best. Maybe the interface could be better if after dismissing a job, it offered "Do you also want to dismiss all jobs from this company?"

Comment: @ssube recruitment agencies are not banned from Jobs, as long as they follow the rules they are allowed on the Jobs site.

Comment: The *the same goes for Companies* statement is not correct. But [there's a feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365674/allow-me-to-undismiss-a-company)