# Weekly (and all other) job matches sucks = spam

Tags: bug, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Sorry for being so blunt, but there's no easy way to tell you: the job matches you suggest are WAY WAY OFF, nowhere close to even being relevant to me and my SO activity. 
For instance, I am active on [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab), [caffe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caffe) and a few others. None of the jobs suggested to me even have remotely related tags on them. A simple match on tags between my profile and the suggested jobs would have eliminated 99% of all proposals. If you do not have any relevant job to suggest - don't spam me!

As things are currently implemented I would like to treat the "suggested jobs" frame at the right hand side of the screen as an "advertisement" and being a privileged user I should be able to browse SO *without* ads.

So *please*
* Either add a "x" icon that would allow me to remove the suggested jobs from my browsing experience
* Or, *drastically* improve the jobs you propose, right now it's just spam.

Comment: Is "tread" a Freudian-slip?

Comment: @BillWoodger I guess my spellchecker has its own personality... Freud would be very intrigued by its slips...

Comment: Actually, there is an "x" icon when you [hover over the jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLuJW.png) but that only removes from the list and doesn't affect anything else like suggesting other jobs iirc. [found it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336481/what-happens-when-i-dismiss-a-job-ad)

Comment: @Lafexlos after "x" clicking dozens of irrelevant jobs I gave up: I will not be a [mechanical turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) for free for SO. If only they would improve the suggested jobs after I removed so many irrelevant ones...

Comment: Ah, your wording on first bullet meant like (at least to me) you didn't know about that "x" icon. Sorry.

Comment: @Lafexlos no need to be sorry. On the contrary, your comment helps to make my question clearer! Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Jobs matches are based upon information in your [job matching preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) in preference of other data we have implied about you based upon things like tags you are active in.

As of right now, it would appear that you liked tags and disliked tags effectively cancel each other out and you don't have any locations specified for us to filter out jobs in your location. In short, we have nothing to work with.

However, completely agree with your point that if we don't have confidence in any of the matches then we should just not send you any jobs at all! I'll have a chat with the team and see whether we can come up with a threshold at which we consider the jobs to not match your interests at all. Will update the post when I know more.

Comment: Apart from "like" and "dislike" tags, can't you see what tags I'm actually active on? What's the point sending me a job description with [tag:java] if I  have only 1 upvote for this tag (compared to hundreds for other tags I consider "active" for me)? Can't you define "most popular" tags for each user and only forward jobs with these tags?

Comment: BTW, thank you for your answer ;)

Comment: Absolutely, but the information you explicitly tell us takes precedence over implied data. You might be active in [tag:matlab] but if you tell us you like working on [tag:php] we'll err on the side of giving you the things you said you liked.

Comment: well, I don't have [tag:java] or [tag:ruby-on-rails] on either my "favorite" tags or my "ignore" tags, I have little to none activity for these tags, yet for some reason SO wants me to get a job that require these skills? Why?

Comment: Favorite and ignored tags are not the tags used by job matching. The ones in your [job match preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) are used there instead. Our thinking is that the tags you want to use for Q&A might not be the same as the ones you want to work with in /jobs.

Comment: That is very odd. I don't recall ever filling these fields, let alone filling the same tags as both a "like" and "dislike"...

Comment: Those fields mirror what is present on your Developer Story, perhaps you mistakenly filled both fields in there?

Comment: As I am not looking for a job at the moment, I did not pay much attention to the "developer story" pages...

Comment: It will have been imported from your CV

Comment: I just found this post, because I went on SO jobs on my iPhone and it is being spammed with Comcast jobs in my area. Almost three pages worth of just Comcast jobs, something has got to be wrong there.